# Coupling AceGen with Abaqus

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I am using Abaqus for nonlinear FEA and, I have generated a UEL (User defined Element Subroutine)using AceGen. But the .log file generated by Abaqus shows a syntax error when I try to run a job using the UEL.
Syntax error is : 'Unterminated quoted string'
.log file isn't indicating the line of code in which the aforementioned error lies.

Is there a solution for this? Any suggestions?